# php mysql update rows where sku not in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I have an array with around 2500 keys:
The structure is like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 452BA [1] => 7fDF-39r73 [2] => 263941)
```

I need to run a code which updates all the rows in my sql table where the content of the field "sku" does not exist in my array.

So something along these lines:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `table` set status = "0" WHERE sku NOT IN (' . implode( ',', array_keys( $array) ) . ')';
```

Comment: and what query does this code generate?

Comment: share `echo $sql;`  output ?

Comment: @Michael are you asking how to put the values inside your current array inside the "sku" column of your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query won't be correct, it will all be like a single value in `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE `table` set status = "0" WHERE sku NOT IN ('452BA,7fDF-39r73,263941');
```

But you need quotes on both sides like:

```
UPDATE `table` set status = "0" WHERE sku NOT IN ('452BA','7fDF-39r73','263941');
```

Try like this:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE `table` set status = "0" WHERE sku NOT IN ("' . implode( '","', array_keys( $array) ) . '")';
```

Comment: @Rishi Thanks for the edit, but it was fine that way too. `mysql` works with both type of quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I understood your question :). You have a database with missing values in some of the rows. Where ever the rows are missing in the database, you would like to place the respective value from your array into the empty (NULL) cell in your database correct?

I recommend you first obtain an array of your table (only two columns needed). From that array you can create a foreach loop that will check if the value inside each specific sku slot is === NULL, and if so, run an SQL statement to fill in that slot.

1) Get the array:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, sku FROM table";
```

Im calling `id` the value that corresponds to the `key` values of your array: `Array ( [0] => 452BA [1] => 7fDF-39r73 [2] => 263941)`

From there you fetch the array (lets call it `$myArray`). Lets also call your previous array `$myOtherArray` (`Array ( [0] => 452BA [1] => 7fDF-39r73 [2] => 263941)`)

Then you create the following loop in php:

```
<?php
foreach ($myArray as $key => $value)
{
  if ($myOtherArray[$key] === NULL)
  {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET sku =".$value." WHERE id = ".$key;
    //run the query
  }
}
?>
```

let me know if that helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

@Michael, I think you are logically right but a slightly changes are required. Please see the following code:

```
$imp_arr = "'".implode( "','", array_keys( $array) )."'";

$sql = 'UPDATE `table` set status = "0" WHERE sku NOT IN (' . $imp_arr . ')';
```

Because at IN if any item is string then it would be surround by single / double quotation.

And one thing I was little bit confused, array_keys( $array) would be only $array.